# How to get values for filtered range with Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to get the range values for my spreadsheet - but only those rows displaying by virtue of the currently-selected filter.

I have tried using `getValues()` on `sheet.getFilter().getRange()`:

```
function applyOverdueFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var filter1 = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria();
  filter1.whenDateBefore(SpreadsheetApp.RelativeDate.TODAY);

  sheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(4, filter1.build());

  var newData = sheet.getFilter().getRange().getValues(); // this doesn't work
  Logger.log(newData);
}
```

However, `newData` contains all the data in my spreadsheet, not just the data showing with the filters applied. How do I only get the filtered data?

Notes: the sheet already has a filter and everything up until the last two lines works perfectly. The reason I don't want to use array filtering in JavaScript is because my filters concern dates and relative dates, which are a lot easier to filter for with Apps Script's Filter Criteria.

Comment: Have you tried something from this article here? https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/google-sheets-api/filters#TOC-Get-filtered-rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take all the data in your spreadsheet, then apply a filter which iterate in that range looking for your criteria. In this case a spreadsheet calls ss as variable then i declare a var calls newData which will be the result of each item[column] == criteria, where columns its the numer of your column, for example column B is 1 and A is 0. and criteria you should know.

For example return item[0] == 'CLOSED'.

```
function applyOverdueFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var newData= ss.filter(function(item){
  return item[column] == criteria;
  });
Logger.log(newData);
}
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: This obtains ALL data from the sheet, then filters within AppsScript. The poster wanted to filter the data on the sheet side, then retrieve only the filtered data, in hopes of speeding this up.